# How do I edit text in a scanned .jpeg?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, scanning, ocr

I need to upload a scanned image as a PDF document.

After scanning the document, I have a `.jpeg` with small text that I want to edit before converting to PDF for the upload.

I have never done this before so I'm really stuck. How can I do this?

Comment: Use GIMP to remove the unwanted text, it's an Image now just cover it up with a white rectangle.

Comment: I just don't want to erase it I want to replace it with just two words

Comment: Put a white rectangle over what you don't want and then put text using the text tool.

Comment: @UriHerrera thanks I will do that and report. Also will anyone notice I have edited the file? An admission board will look at it and think I faked it

Comment: Well, it depends if you make a good job editing the text and the font you use as replacement matches the of the document it'd be quite hard to notice.

Comment: If it's not too much can u please edit it for me? With your skill it will take a minute maximum. Please please please

Comment: @Mysterio can it wait 9 hours? If yes, email me the document and I'll do it, it's easy. If not, see the OCR answer below & good luck.

Comment: @TomBrossman yes it can wait I just have to send it by friday. Please what's your e-mail address?

Comment: No problem, my profile has a couple websites you can use to get in touch. I just did a bunch of these, page images of old WW2 documents.  Yours will be so easy in comparison.

Comment: @TomBrossman I just e-mailed them with the instructions. God bless you

Comment: IF this involves an admissions board, is it wise to edit text and try to make it appear authentic? Depending on the situation this could be illegal.

Comment: Exactly why I want someone well experienced with these editors to handle it. This could damage my application process and cost me a my admission. It's not illegal just a grammatical error

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To make text in a `.jpeg` editable you need Optical Character Recognition (OCR) software. 
I use `ocrfeeder`.

```
sudo apt-get install ocrfeeder
```

To open an image file click on the 'plus' (+) sign.
[image]
After you have opened the image, click on the next icon to the right to run OCR.
[image]
After is has finished OCR'ing the image, you can select the text you want on the left, and copy it out on the right.
[image]

The easiest way to get the text out is to just copy it over to LibreOffice.
With a little editing, my copy looks very similar.

[image]

After you make the required changes you can export them as `.pdf` by clicking 'export as pdf' from the LibreOffice toobar.
[image]

Ultimately its best to scan to `.pdf` if you can.  If you can't this works very well.

**NOTE:**  OCR is not 100% accurate, you may have to correct errors, and the more formatting your document has, the harder it will be.

Comment: +1, This is definitely gives the best results. The other methods involving manipulation of the JPEG images can look quite bad if the text is aliased, OCR avoids this problem.

Comment: @TimWolla It depends if the JPG is graphics or text based. As I read the question, the JPG was a graphic with some text.

Answer (score 10):

You can't edit text in a JPG, but you remove the text and add new text.

For images, try **gimp** (open source alternative to Photoshop). Open the image with gimp, then use the eraser tool to erase the old text. Then use the text tool to add new text.

Or, use **inkscape**, which is a vector graphics program (similar to Adobe Illustrator). Create a new SVG file and paste in your JPG. Then, cover up the old text with a new text box.

I would start with **gimp** but for your image maybe inkscape works better. You can install either code from the software center, or use these lines in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gimp

sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

Answer (score 7):

We can also edit text on top of an image with Libre Office from where we can also easily export this files as PDF.

- Open your document to insert the image with *Insert -> Picture -> From File...*.

  [image]
- Then choose *"Wrap -> In Background"* from the right click context menu on the picture you just inserted.
- Write any text above the image (but we will have to place it with newlines, and spaces or tabstops). Any preexisting text needs to be overwritten. In the example below I have done this by choosing a black background and a white font colour.

  [image]
- Finally we can do *"File -> Export as PDF..."*.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly edit text in an image file. You can edit the image file using a program such as `gimp` and place new text on top of old but that's it. Sorry.

Comment: Search for [OCR software](https://duckduckgo.com/Optical_character_recognition). You've misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I don't want to printscreen a page and convert it. Then I use this little script:

[How can instantaneously extract text from a screen area using OCR tools?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280475/how-can-instantaneously-extract-text-from-a-screen-area-using-ocr-tools)

Its the fastest way to convert picture to text for me and it works almost very good.

So my suggestion is, you scan the document and open the picture. At the same time, you open an editor and copy the parts you need to the editor. 
With easystroke you make a gesture for the script, it is really easy and fast.