# How can instantaneously extract text from a screen area using OCR tools?

Tags: 12.10, software-recommendation, screenshot, ocr

In Ubuntu 12.10, if I type

```
gnome-screenshot -a | tesseract output
```

it returns:

```
** Message: Unable to use GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.
```

How can I select a text from the screen and convert it to text (clipboard or document)?

Thank you!

Comment: You get that error using only `gnome-screenshot -a`? Also why you pipe the output to tesseract? If i'm not wrong gnome-screenshot saves the picture on a file, and does not "print" it...

Comment: Warning should be harmless if I look through bugzilla. Question: what is the `auto-save-directory`? And did it drop anything in there? Interesting link: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=85683

Comment: gnome-screenchot -a -c is supposed to copy selection to clipboard,isnt it?. but piping it to tesseract gives the same error. the default directory is home/pictures (works well).

Comment: Just done this using gnome-screenshot - I then had to edit the files to decrease the colour depth from 16m to 2 (it was black text on white background, but with today's fancy font smoothing and so-on, it wasn't *really* black) I then had to scale the image up to 200% of the original before I got an accurate OCR from tesseract - but it worked really well once I'd done that.

Comment: @SteveLake Hey Steve, thanks for the suggestion. I edited the script to programmatically modify the image in the way you described before OCRing it. Detection rate should now be much better.

Comment: A list of tools is given at https://github.com/dynobo/normcap#similar-open-source-tools.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Maybe there is already some tool that does that, but you can also create a simple script with some screenshot tool and tesseract, as you are trying to use.

Take as an example this script (in my system I saved it as `/usr/local/bin/screen_ts`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Dependencies: tesseract-ocr imagemagick scrot

select tesseract_lang in eng rus equ ;do break;done
# Quick language menu, add more if you need other languages.

SCR_IMG=`mktemp`
trap "rm $SCR_IMG*" EXIT

scrot -s $SCR_IMG.png -q 100 
# increase quality with option -q from default 75 to 100
# Typo "$SCR_IMG.png000" does not continue with same name.


mogrify -modulate 100,0 -resize 400% $SCR_IMG.png 
#should increase detection rate

tesseract $SCR_IMG.png $SCR_IMG &> /dev/null
cat $SCR_IMG.txt
exit
```

And with clipboard support:

```bash
#!/bin/bash 
# Dependencies: tesseract-ocr imagemagick scrot xsel

select tesseract_lang in eng rus equ ;do break;done
# quick language menu, add more if you need other languages.

SCR_IMG=`mktemp`
trap "rm $SCR_IMG*" EXIT

scrot -s $SCR_IMG.png -q 100    
# increase image quality with option -q from default 75 to 100

mogrify -modulate 100,0 -resize 400% $SCR_IMG.png 
#should increase detection rate

tesseract $SCR_IMG.png $SCR_IMG &> /dev/null
cat $SCR_IMG.txt | xsel -bi

exit
```

It uses `scrot` to take the screen, `tesseract` to recognize the text and `cat` to display the result. The clipboard version additionally utilizes `xsel` to pipe the output into the clipboard.

[image: sample usage]

**NOTE**: `scrot`, `xsel`, `imagemagick` and `tesseract-ocr` are not installed by default but are available from the the default repositories.

You may be able to replace `scrot` with `gnome-screenshot`, but it may take a lot of work. Regarding the output you can use anything that can read a text file (open with Text Editor, show the recognized text as a notification, etc).

---

**GUI version of the script**

Here's a simple graphical version of the OCR script including a language selection dialog:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# DEPENDENCIES: tesseract-ocr imagemagick scrot yad
# AUTHOR:       Glutanimate 2013 (http://askubuntu.com/users/81372/)
# NAME:         ScreenOCR
# LICENSE:      GNU GPLv3
#
# BASED ON:     OCR script by Salem (http://askubuntu.com/a/280713/81372)

TITLE=ScreenOCR # set yad variables
ICON=gnome-screenshot

# - tesseract won't work if LC_ALL is unset so we set it here
# - you might want to delete or modify this line if you 
#   have a different locale:

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

# language selection dialog
LANG=$(yad \
    --width 300 --entry --title "$TITLE" \
    --image=$ICON \
    --window-icon=$ICON \
    --button="ok:0" --button="cancel:1" \
    --text "Select language:" \
    --entry-text \
    "eng" "ita" "deu")

# - You can modify the list of available languages by editing the line above
# - Make sure to use the same ISO codes tesseract does (man tesseract for details)
# - Languages will of course only work if you have installed their respective
#   language packs (https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list)

RET=$? # check return status

if [ "$RET" = 252 ] || [ "$RET" = 1 ]  # WM-Close or "cancel"
  then
      exit
fi

echo "Language set to $LANG"

SCR_IMG=$(mktemp) # create tempfile
trap "rm $SCR_IMG*" EXIT # make sure tempfiles get deleted afterwards

scrot -s "$SCR_IMG".png -q 100 #take screenshot of area
mogrify -modulate 100,0 -resize 400% "$SCR_IMG".png # postprocess to prepare for OCR
tesseract -l "$LANG" "$SCR_IMG".png "$SCR_IMG" # OCR in given language
xsel -bi < "$SCR_IMG".txt # pass to clipboard
exit
```

Aside from the dependencies listed above you will need to install the [Zenity fork YAD from the webupd8 PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/yad-zenity-on-steroids-display.html) to make the script work.

Comment: works greate in terminal! thank you! I want to screencopy codetext from tutorials for testing. How to use scrot to clipboard?

Comment: what happens with the tempfiles?

Comment: The tempfiles stay there until you reboot your computer. If that is a problem to you, you can just delete them at the end (`rm $SCR_IMG.png $SCR_IMG.txt`).

Comment: `scrot` by itself can't use the clipboard. But there are tools like `xclip` or `xsel` that may do what you need if it is to copy/paste text.

Comment: Adding to Salem's answer: If you're running KDE then you can call another script to automatically send the text you've generated to the clipboard, ready to paste. You'll find a suitable script [here](http://milianw.de/code-snippets/access-klipper-clipboard-on-cli-under-kde4). Follow the instructions on that page to install that script. Then all you need to is add `| clipboard` to the end of the final line of Salem's script.

Comment: It works in my system. Awesome.

Comment: To capture text in other languages, do we need to install specific fonts 
? What other languages are available in tesseract_lang ?

Comment: @thethakuri OCR is not language dependent, but character dependant, meaning it will work for Latin script regardless of the language, but you might need Cyrillic support if you are capturing Russian. You can check using "apt-cache search tesseract" in the terminal. It'll show you a list of all supported languages.

Comment: @Salem I have a similar question related to this question. Can you please check it out https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038099/capture2text-alternative-capture-text-from-screen-directly-in-ubuntu-mate

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. In `cat $SCR_IMG | xsel -bi # pass to clipboard` you may need to change $SCR_IMG to $SCR_IMG.txt, because, at least for me, tesseract automatically appends the .txt extension to its output

Comment: The current version is weird. It has a `select tesseract_lang` command, but the variable is not used. Besides, a select command cannot work if you execute the script with a keyboard shortcut (instead of having to open a terminal and type the script name).  So, I removed the  select command and added the language I wanted explicitly with the option -l in the tesseract command. I created a desktop shortcut to the script as explained here https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en . For some reason, an extra  `sleep 0.5` was needed at the start of the script.

Comment: I could replace `scrot -s $SCR_IMG.png -q 100` with `gnome-screenshot -a -f $SCR_IMG.png` with no problem at all.,

Answer (score 19):

I created a free and open source program for this purpose:

https://danpla.github.io/dpscreenocr/

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Awesome tool, solved my problem. I did have to compile from source to get it to work on Ubuntu 18, but it was very straightforward - just install dependencies, and run cmake. Then just use the hot key to start the selection, hot key to end, and you've got the text in history!

Comment: Excellent tool! (That is, Tesseract sometimes makes mistakes, but this is not the tool's problem). I installed it on Ubuntu via launchpad.net, and it told me that I need to install Tesseract languages. After I installed a few languages manually (via aptitude), everything worked! Use `aptitude search tesseract` or `apt-cache search tesseract` to see the list of languages. IMPORTANT: you use **the same hotkey** to begin and end text area selection. And select the "Copy text to clipboard" option in "Actions".

Comment: Awesome tool, you can star it on github over here https://github.com/danpla/dpscreenocr

Comment: Very usefull tool! Starred it on github. Thanks @danpla

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work on Wayland...

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if any one need my solution. Here is one that runs with wayland.

It shows the character-recognition in a Text-Editor and if you add the paramter "yes" you got the translation from the goggle trans tool (Internet connection is mandatory) Before you can use it install tesseract-ocr imagemagick and google-trans. Start the script i.e. in gnome with Alt+F2 when you see your text that you want to recognize. Move the courser arround the text. Thats it.
This script was testetd only for gnome. For other window manager it musst be accommodate. To translate the text in other languages replace the language ID in line 25.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Dependencies: tesseract-ocr imagemagick google-trans

translate="no"
translate=$1

SCR_IMG=`mktemp`
trap "rm $SCR_IMG*" EXIT

gnome-screenshot -a -f $SCR_IMG.png  
# increase quality with option -q from default 75 to 100
# Typo "$SCR_IMG.png000" does not continue with same name.


mogrify -modulate 100,0 -resize 400% $SCR_IMG.png 
#should increase detection rate

tesseract $SCR_IMG.png $SCR_IMG &> /dev/null

if [ $translate = "yes" ] ; then

        trans :de file://$SCR_IMG.txt -o $SCR_IMG.translate.txt
        gnome-text-editor $SCR_IMG.translate.txt
        else
        gnome-text-editor $SCR_IMG.txt
fi

exit
```

Answer (score 2):

I just done a [blogging](http://diannaoxiaobai.blogspot.my/2016/04/howto-print-screen.html) about how to use screenshot in modern day. Even though i target Chinese but the screen cast and code is in english. OCR is merely one of the feature.

Feature for my OCR:

- Open in konsole+vimx OR gedit to further edit.
- For vimx+english, enable spelling checking.
- Support dynamic language selection without hard code.
- Progress dialog when converting and tesseracting which is slow.

Function code:

```
function ocr () {
    tmpj="$1"
    tmpocr="$2"
    tmpocr_p="$3"
    atom="$(tesseract --list-langs 2>&1)"; atom=(`echo "${atom#*:}"`); atom=(`echo "$(printf 'FALSE\n%s\n' "${atom[@]}")"`); atom[0]='True'
    ans=(`yad --center --height=200 --width=300 --separator='|' --on-top --list --title '' --text='Select Languages:' --radiolist --column '✓' --column 'Languages' "${atom[@]}" 2>/dev/null`) && ans="$(echo "${ans:5:-1}")" &&  convert "$tmpj[x2000]" -unsharp 15.6x7.8+2.69+0 "$tmpocr_p" | yad --on-top --title '' --text='Converting ...' --progress --pulsate --auto-close 2>/dev/null && tesseract "$tmpocr_p" "$tmpocr" -l "$ans" 2>>/tmp/tesseract.log | yad --percentage=50 --on-top --title '' --text='Tesseracting ...' --progress --pulsate --auto-close 2>/dev/null && if [[ "$ans" == 'eng' ]]; then konsole -e "vimx -c 'setlocal spell spelllang=en_us' -n $tmpocr.txt" 2>/dev/null; else gedit "$tmpocr.txt"; fi
    rm "$tmpocr_p"
}
```

Caller code:

```
for cmd in "mktemp" "convert" "tesseract" "gedit" "konsole" "vimx" "yad"; do 
    command -v $cmd >/dev/null 2>&1 || {  LANG=POSIX; xmessage "Require $cmd but it's not installed.  Aborting." >&2; exit 1; }; :;
done
tmpj="$(mktemp /tmp/`date +"%s_%Y-%m-%d"`_XXXXXXXXXX.png)"
tmpocr="$(mktemp -u /tmp/`date +"%s_%Y-%m-%d"`_ocr_XXXXX)"
tmpocr_p="$tmpocr"+'.png'
gnome-screenshot -a -f "$tmpj" 2>&1 >/dev/null | ts >>/tmp/gnome_area_PrtSc_error.log
ocr $tmpj $tmpocr $tmpocr_p &
```

Combine this 2 code in single shell script to run.

Screenshot 1:
[image]

Screenshot 2:
[image]

Comment: seems like a decent solution but the readability of your script is very bad

Answer (score 2):

This single line script (based on https://askubuntu.com/a/1084151/456438) is to be used with a keyboard shortcut, so that you can ocr anywhere in the screen without having to open a terminal, just as illustrated in this image.

[image: usage example]

```
#!/bin/bash
# Dependencies: convert imagemagick xsel tesseract-ocr-fra [tesseract-ocr-jpn ...]  

convert x: -modulate 100,0 -resize 400% -set density 300 png:- |
  tesseract stdin stdout -l fra+eng+jpn --psm 3 | 
  sed 's/'$(printf '%b' '\014')'//g;s/|/I/g' | 
  xsel -bi
```

Change the `--psm` and `-l` options as needed. Examples:

- `--psm 10` is for an image with a single character
- `--psm 3` is the default.
- `-l fra+eng+jpn` will first consider French, then English, then Japanese.

Adapt the sed post processing to your need. `sed 's/'$(printf '%b' '\014')'//g;s/|/I/g'` removes the Form Feed character (octal 014) and replaces the vertical bar "|" with "I".

Use the standard instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en to create a keyboard shortcut that will execute the script. Put the script in ~/bin or anywhere in your path environment variable to avoid using the full path to your script.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is anytime a new screenshot files appear in the folder run tesseract OCR on it and open in a file editor.

You can leave this running script in the output directory of your favorite screen shot output directory

```
#cat wait_for_it.sh
inotifywait -m . -e create -e moved_to |
    while read path action file; do
        echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
        cd "$path"
        if [ ${file: -4} == ".png" ]; then
                tesseract "$file" "$file"
                sleep 1
                gedit "$file".txt &
        fi

    done
```

You will need this to be istalled

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
sudo apt install inotify-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to install `mogrify` and `scrot` so here's another way using `gnome-screenshot` in Ubuntu. I added a keyboard shortcut to run the command to trigger a snapshot in Ubuntu and send the OCR output text to the clipboard.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

SCR_IMG=".screentemp.jpg"
TEMP_TXT=".screentext.txt"

gnome-screenshot -a --file=$SCR_IMG

tesseract $SCR_IMG $TEMP_TXT -l eng

cat $TEMP_TXT* | xsel -b

rm $SCR_IMG $TEMP_TXT*
```

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: https://github.com/SR-Hossain/image2textSR

Details:
I use flameshot for this like below...

```
sudo apt-get install flameshot
pip install pytesseract pyperclip
sudo nano /image2text.py
```

Paste this code in the image2text.py and save using ctrl+x > y > Enter

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import pyperclip
extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('/tmp/a.png'))
pyperclip.copy(extracted_text)
```

Now run this command whenever you want to copy text from selected part of your screen...

```
rm -f /tmp/a.png && flameshot gui --path /tmp/a.png && python3 /image2text.py
```

I have created a custom shortcut (mapped to shift+prtsc) in my linux, so I just press shift+prtsc whenever I want to copy text from image file...

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command.

```
maim -s | convert - -units PixelsPerInch -resample 300 -sharpen 12x6.0 - | tesseract -l eng stdin stdout | sed '$d' | perl -0777 -pe 's/^(\s*\n)+|(\s*\n)+$//g' | xclip -in -selection clipboard
```

Here I am using `sed '$d' | perl -0777 -pe 's/^(\s*\n)+|(\s*\n)+$//g'` to remove blank lines from beginning and end of the output.

You can also use [normcap](https://github.com/dynobo/normcap) which is a simple python program for the specific task you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found [NormCap](https://github.com/dynobo/normcap#normcap) the tool with the less friction. Using tesseract directly lead to many wrong characters.

[image: Selecting a region in NormCap]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [frog](https://github.com/TenderOwl/Frog). It is available as a snap and also works with Wayland.