# better "screenshot-reader" in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, display

According to [How can instantaneously extract text from a screen area using OCR tools?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280475/how-can-instantaneously-extract-text-from-a-screen-area-using-ocr-tools) and system responses I use

```
sh screen_ts.sh
```

, the content of which is

```
#!/bin/bash
scrot -s zkoSCR_IMG.png
tesseract zkoSCR_IMG.png zkoSCR
cat zkoSCR.txt|xclip -i -selection clipboard
```

. The Terminal responses

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica
```

, but the text is recognized with too many errors, even in the Terminal window itself. The ABBYY Screenshot Reader in Windows XP is far better. Can I achieve such better results in the Ubuntu? How? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489824/how-do-i-choose-between-tesseract-and-opencv for a discussion of the subject.

Comment: Hey Tomas. I edited the answer in the Q&A you linked and updated it with an enhanced script. The detection rate should now be much better. Hope it works for you. I will flag this question as a duplicate because I think both Q&As cover the exact same issue.