# How can I use OCR on a partial screen capture to get text?

Tags: screenshot, translation, japanese, ocr

When I was still using Windows I loved using the [capture2text](http://capture2text.sourceforge.net/) OCR program to grab Japanese kanji from manga and dump them into jisho.org, and was wondering how I could get the same functionality on Ubuntu. Namely:

1. Take a partial screenshot upon hitting a designated hotkey (click+drag style).
2. Process the image through an OCR engine.
3. Output the result into the clipboard.

Answer (score 4):

Based off of [this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/280713/638387) (the 2nd one) I whittled the script down to this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Dependencies: tesseract-ocr imagemagick gnome-screenshot xclip

SCR="/home/takingitcasual/Documents/Translate/temp"

gnome-screenshot -a -f $SCR.png

mogrify -modulate 100,0 -resize 400% $SCR.png 
#should increase detection rate

tesseract $SCR.png $SCR -psm 10 -l jpn
cat $SCR.txt | xclip -selection clipboard
#you can only scan one character at a time

exit
```

Some goals I had with the modified file:

1. Removing the need for sudo (to allow for easy hotkey binding)
2. Replacing scrot (the way gnome-screenshot works looks much nicer IMO)
3. Simplify the script to something I can more easily understand (removal of temp files)
4. Limit recognition to one character at a time. (recognition was abysmal without that "-psm 10", and Tesseract kept throwing "empty page" errors as well)

Another two things I did were:

```
chmod a+x /home/takingitcasual/Documents/Translate/
```

and setting the temp files permissions to read/write for all. Not sure if it was redundant to do both.

Last thing was giving the bash command

```
bash /home/takingitcasual/Documents/Translate/screen_ts.sh
```

a shortcut via [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/591605/638387).

If anybody has suggestions on modifying the script or anything else I'd love to hear it. (I have no previous experience with scripting, so I'm sure it can be improved.)

Comment: I have a similar question related to this question. Can you please check it out  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038099/capture2text-alternative-capture-text-from-screen-directly-in-ubuntu-mate

Comment: --psm 10 is useful if the image has a single character.

Comment: -l jpn is useful if the text is in Japanese.

Comment: -psm is a typo. It must be --psm