# Capture2Text - Alternative (Capture text from Screen Directly) in Ubuntu Mate

Tags: bash, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 18.04, mate

I found few similar questions in this site but could not complete the process.

From the Answer of [How can instantaneously extract text from a screen area using OCR tools?](https://askubuntu.com/a/280713/598062) and [How can I use OCR on a partial screen capture to get text?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868089/how-can-i-use-ocr-on-a-partial-screen-capture-to-get-text)

First I installed the dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
sudo apt-get install scrot
sudo apt-get install xsel
```

Then I put the following script in `/home/blueray/Documents/Translate/screen_ts.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Dependencies: tesseract-ocr imagemagick scrot xsel

SCR_IMG=`mktemp`
trap "rm $SCR_IMG*" EXIT

scrot -s $SCR_IMG.png -q 100    
# increase image quality with option -q from default 75 to 100

mogrify -modulate 100,0 -resize 400% $SCR_IMG.png 
#should increase detection rate

tesseract $SCR_IMG.png $SCR_IMG &> /dev/null
cat $SCR_IMG.txt | xsel -bi

exit
```

Please note that I removed

```
select tesseract_lang in eng rus equ ;do break;done
# Quick language menu, add more if you need other languages.
```

In the hope that it will only consider english. **Please let me know if this is not the case.**

Now when I put

```
bash /home/blueray/Documents/Translate/screen_ts.sh
```

It works as I wanted.

In windows, with Capture2Text, I used to use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to capture part of the screen as text. So, I checked [How do I set a custom keyboard shortcut to control volume?](https://askubuntu.com/a/591605/598062)

I went to `Menu-> Searched for Keyboard Shortcuts -> Click`

[image]

1. Then I clicked `Add`
2. Name: Capture2Text
3. Command: `bash /home/blueray/Documents/Translate/screen_ts.sh`
4. Clicked `Apply`
5. Clicked On Shortcut on the right.
6. Pressed  <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>

Now when I press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>, nothing happens. **What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need "scrot".  Imagemagick (which provided "mogrify") can do the job of screen capture.   You also don't need to save an intermediate image, as "tesseract" can accept an image on standard input.

As such the above simplifies to...

```
convert x: -modulate 100,0 -resize 400% -set density 300 png:- |
  tesseract stdin stdout | xsel -bi
```

However I also added the following to my version of the script, to pop up the text on screen so you can check it.

```
xsel -po | xless - &
```

Of course tesseract could use some improvements for some fonts!  For example 'f's in some fonts have a small hook that makes tesseract think they are 'P's!  Arrghhhh...

EDIT:  Full script I use is located at...

[https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/#capture_ocr](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/software/#capture_ocr)

I link this to a 'hotkey' (Meta-Print) using my window manager (openbox), so I can use it at any time.

If you can't use a hotkey, and need to uncover the part of the screen containing the text you can always launch it with a delay...

sleep 5; capture_ocr

Enjoy

Comment: Can you please give the full script so that I can just copy-paste (with `xsel -po | xless - &`).

Comment: Updated answer with link to full script  (and many other scripts).

Comment: Full script that works for me: `convert x: -modulate 100,0 -resize 400% -set density 300 png:- | tesseract --dpi 300 stdin stdout | xsel -bi`. Initially, tesseract was printing `Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.` Addition of `--dpi 300` parameter fixed it (found it on [GitHub](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1702#issuecomment-473509913)). Setup: `tesseract 4.1.1` on Fedora 33.

Answer (score 1):

I had to tweek @anthony 's script so it would work on my box (Kubuntu 18.04):

Instead of the `convert` line, I used:

`import -resize 300% +dither  png:- |`

Also, I removed the trailing minus `-` sign from the last line, so:

`xsel -ob | $XPAGER`

Working great.