# Is there package I can install for using a webcam as a document scanner?

Tags: webcam, scanner

My scanner recently broke and I'm looking for a way to scan multi-page documents using my web camera.  Ideally, I'd like some sort of program that would analyse/average multiple images from the webcam to produce a crisper image inside a program like XSane.

If I had a better camera I could probably just take a picture with cheese / kameraka and then aggregate the output and convert to pdf.  However, my webcam quality is too low, and I'd prefer the capture program to be be aggregating the images into a single file.

Comment: You might be interested in this question too: http://askubuntu.com/q/225872/44179

Comment: Great link!  However I let google do the OCRing for me - hence the need for PDF output.